# Package pdftex.def error PDF mode expected

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex

Took me 6 hours today and still doesn't work,
the error is :

```
Package pdftex.def error PDF mode expected mf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
```

Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=90]{histogram_DSC_activity.eps}

\section{Title}
\end{document}
```

when I change it to

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I get `cannot determine size of graphic in the figure file`.
I check all remedy on google and here but ... also tried picture with pdf format.

Comment: Just to confirm---are you using `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: I am using latex

Comment: Then it sounds like your EPS file is missing a bounding box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDFLaTeX does not support EPS files. However, some modern LaTeX distributions will try to automatically convert it to a PDF image, which maybe this doesn't work in your case. It would be also possible that the size information, namely the bounding box, in that EPS file is missing.

If you are using `latex`, i.e. the DVI mode of LaTeX, which supports EPS then you should remove the incorrect `pdftex` option from the `graphicx` package. The packages should be able to figure out the used driver by themselves, so you should avoid such options anyway. If you are using `pdflatex` then it would be better to convert the EPS to a PDF file manually, e.g. using the `epstopdf` tool (I'm not sure if it comes with the Windows version, but I think so). You need to change the `.eps` extension to `.pdf` then, of course. You can also drop the extension and LaTeX will look for files with the given base name with all supported extensions, i.e. `\includegraphics{file}` will use `file.eps` for `latex` and `file.pdf` (or `file.png`, `file.jpg`) for `pdflatex`.

Comment: the order in which extensions are tried is `.png`, `.pdf`, `.jpg`, `.mps`, `.jpeg`, `.jbig2`, `.jb2`; after these, uppercase extensions are tried in the same order (with the exception of MPS). It's probably useful to remark this, since it can cause some head scratching.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for mentioned that. I knew it but didn't recall the exact order. We should then also mention that the order can be changed by `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{<comma separated list of extensions>}`.

Comment: that might be useful; however users should always choose the best format for their pictures: PNG, PDF and JPEG are each suitable for their particular kind of pictures.

Comment: Seems pdflatex is a bit better ! Now I don't have picture on my preview !

Comment: @egreg could you elaborate about the ordering?! any simple example ?!