# Why OSX Texstudio cannot compile this?

Tags: texstudio, mac, mactex, auto-pst-pdf

I have tried the following MWE on Windows 7 and OSX (Mavericks) with different front ends. Windows Tex system is Miktex 2.9 and on OSX it is MacTeX 2013. In all cases PdfLaTeX is run and write18 (or shell escape) is enabled. The result:

1. Winedt+Miktex on windows, code compiles with no problem.
2. Texstudio+Miktex on windows, code compiles with no problem.
3. Texmaker+Miktex on windows, code compiles with no problem.
4. Texshop+MacTex on Mavericks, code compiles with no problem.
5. Texmaker+MacTeX on Mavericks, code compiles with no problem.
6. Texstudio+MacTeX on Mavericks, code **does not** compile correctly, the figure does not show and is replaced by an empty square.

My guess is that there is something wrong with the way auto-pst-pdf operates when it is called via Texstudio under OSX. Probably in the first run that latex+dvips+ps2pdf is called via shell.

Can anyone verify this odd behavior of Texstudio under OSX or suggest a solution? Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
This is a test. 
\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=5in]{example-image-a.eps}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course we do not have that image? And please make up your mind, your list says it is TeXShop, but you keep talking about TeXStudio.

Comment: @dalief Thanks. Question corrected, should read Texstudio as you found. The image is a standard test image that comes with MikTeX and MacTex and if one runs the program under any of these distributions will see that the image is found by the system

Comment: Exactly how is it being compiled in Texstudio? Which options, are they *exactly* the same as in Texmaker? What does the `.log` file tell you?

Comment: @dalief For both Texmaker and Texstudio (OSX) the command line (from preferences) is: "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex      and the log file for Texstudio is:    LaTeX Warning: File `qq-pics.pdf' not found on input line 8.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `qq-pics.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.       As you see, Texstudio under OSX fails to generate qq-pics.pdf file in the latex+dvips+ps2pdf phase (qq.tex is the name of the MWE file).

Comment: Just for the fun of it, what happens if you run `/usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode qq.tex` by hand in a shell? Just to make sure that this is the editors fault. Why are there `--` for `--shell -escape` and not for the other options?

Comment: @dalief Works fine as it should. In fact calling the shell is what both Texshop and Texmaker do. The problem with Texstudio is that it somehow fails to call the shell correctly in its latex+dvips+ps2pdf phase.

Comment: Pass, just installed TeXStudio on my linux and it works just fine with those settings. You'll need someone with a Mac to help.

Comment: Are instances 4, 5 and 6 on the same machine, in the same user account and with the same working directory?

Comment: @cfr yes, exactly the same conditions.

Comment: On OS X 10.7.5, same PdfLaTeX setting, the generated error is:


>  ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `try-pics.pdf' not found.

and the resulting pdf contains a box containing "try-pics.pdf".

Answer (score 2):

On OS X 10.7.5, texstudio_2.6.6e_osx_qt5, the MWE works without error if I comment out the line

`\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`

Omission of the `.eps` extension in the `\includegraphics` line also does no harm, as indicated at [Package pdftex.def error PDF mode expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/package-pdftex-def-error-pdf-mode-expected)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the error reproduced when the line is retained?

Comment: deleting auto-pst-pdf and the .eps extension works for **this** example, but I have a source file with a lot of pstricks and psfrag codes. For that source using auto-pst-pdf is essential. Also it is interesting to find out why texstudio under MaxTeX shows this oddity whereas Texmaker and Texshop work with no problem and the windows version of Texstudio also works fine.

Comment: @Sean Alfred: I answered this question in a comment to the original question, which I repeat:
  
On OS X 10.7.5, same PdfLaTeX setting, the generated error is: > ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `try-pics.pdf' not found. and the resulting pdf contains a box containing "try-pics.pdf".

Comment: @per  Deleting the .eps was not essential for getting the MWE to work.